# repeat javascript with boolean if and else and make it stop

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code

```
counter = 0

if (counter <= 11) 
{
    counter = counter + 1
    let minuscule = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let majuscule ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    leschiffre = "0123456789"
    lesSignes = "!@#$%^&*(){}[]=<>/,."
    // Une string est un tableau de charactere 
    console.log(minuscule.length);
    console.log(majuscule.length);
    console.log(leschiffre.length);

    let uneminusculeAuHasard = minuscule[ Math.floor (Math.random()*26)];
    let uneMajusculeAuHasard = majuscule[ Math.floor (Math.random()*26)];
    let unChiffreAuHasard =   leschiffre[ Math.floor (Math.random()*10)];
    let unSigneauHasard   =    lesSignes[ Math.floor (Math.random()*10)];

    listpass = [uneminusculeAuHasard, uneMajusculeAuHasard, unChiffreAuHasard, unSigneauHasard]

    console.log(listpass);    
} else 
{
    return "stop"
}
```

The random digits are stored inside of a list and sent to the console I would like to know how i can make it repeat itself (a bit like in python)

I made this random password generator and want to make it stop after generating 10 random codes
I used a variable counter to add up and repeat the code until that specific variable (counter) stops when it reaches a value of 10 but it can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Put it in a loop. `for (let counter = 0; counter <= 11; counter++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to create an amount of passwords with a specific length.
If you don't specify the length it generates a random length.

```
function generateRandomPassword(amount, length = 0) {
    let minuscule = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let majuscule = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let leschiffre = "0123456789";
    let lesSignes = "!@#$%^&*(){}[]=<>/,.";

    let password = "";
    let characters = minuscule + majuscule + leschiffre + lesSignes;
    let passwords = [];

    // Loop to generate amount of passwords
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        // Loop to generate password of length. If length is 0, generate random length
        for (let j = 0; j < (length === 0 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1 : length); j++) {
            password += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
        }
        passwords.push(password);
        password = "";
    }

    return passwords;
}
```

Returns an array of created passwords, something like:

```js
generateRandomPassword(5, 10)
['[u[VE4mhcd', '6/gw%d(h9n', 'oXY<P*^V>^', 'GNEc2yU*C(', 'JPwn34VH0y']
```

```js
generateRandomPassword(5)
['%sNR', 'z,tSq=P!W=', 'rc[1R5*', 'X1q&', 'RP3,vYl<']
```

Comment: the way you showed me is good but i need to use only the variables and ways i used on my code and use else and if with a counter that counts up to 10 and stops but i'll use what you showed me thank you for the feedback